# How to check whether a specific UiViewcontroller(Tabbar Embedded) is in the navigationController rack?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar

I have a SignInVc as a starting point and a skip button. If user taps skip, e goes to home page and when he taps any button he is pushed to SignInVc.

The homeVC has TabBar, like its one of the 4 tab bar Vc's.

```
                   if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
                        for controller in viewControllers
                        {
                            if controller == (tabBarController?.viewControllers![0]){
                                print("FOUND IT")
                            }
                            print(controller)
                        }
                    }
```

While debugging with breakpoints, i can see the home page in **navigationController?.viewControllers**

But i cannot access it!!, the print is not executed. What should i use in the RHS of == ?

The plan is to push to the homeVC  instead of print code.

**EDIT:**

I'm adding the screen shots of the debug below

Here i want to get to the view controller at **Index 2**

[image: tabbar StoryBoard]

[image: Home StoryBoard]

[[image: Debug window][1]]

[image: Debug]

Comment: Please, add screen with your hierarchy in storyboard or code where you allocate tabBarController, navigation controller and homeViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether am right,

logically declare a global variable,

`var initiateHomePage: Bool?` // declare above or outside any swift file

For button actions

case 1

```
  @IBAction func skipButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
      initiateHomePage = true // should go homepage
    
    }
```

case 2

```
  @IBAction func anyButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
      initiateHomePage = false // should go SignInVC
    
    }
```

Atlast

while executing

```
  if initiateHomePage == true {
      // redirect to home page
      // use this to redirect to tab bar 
       if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
                            for controller in viewControllers
                            {
                                if controller == (tabBarController?.viewControllers![0]){
                                    print("FOUND IT")
                                }
                                print(controller)
                            }
                        } 

    //  or use this 
    let ViewController:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Module", bundle: nil)
        let tabBarController = ViewController.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
     
    } else {
      // redirect to SignINVC 
     
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that you have such hierarchy as you've described.
Really you have

```
NavigationController -> TabBarController -> HomeViewController or
TabBarController -> NavigationController -> HomeViewController
```

Properties `.navigationController` and `.tabBarController` find nearest accessible Navigation and TabBar controller.
Just exam your hierarchy in storyboard or in code, and you will fix your problem.

**UPD**.
Based on your screen, you should find tabBar controller first, and find HomeViewController in tabBarController. I think, the code should looks like:

```
if let tabBar = navController.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is UITabBarController} ){
    let homeController = tabController.viewControllers?.first(where: { $0 is HomeViewController})
    print("Home controller: \(home)")
}
```

Comment: Its in 'NavigationController -> TabBarController -> HomeViewController'

Comment: I've updated my answer, you should find in tabBar's viewControllers array, not in navBarController's viewControllers array.

Comment: i'm getting nil up there,